# Opening Eclipse linked content from "Help Content" in plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to develop an eclipse plugin (GUI) which will include a button that I want linked to some page in the Eclipse Help Content, according to some parameters chosen in the plugin (gui), so when I press it, the content opens.

I saw that help content are found on, and can be opened in a browser like way using their http://xx.xx.xx.xx/help/..(rest of path)/(my page).html .

my question is how can i get this xx.xx.xx.xx in the code  or the whole path so I can need only to concatenate (my page). (what you see in red in pic).
I assume this is some field in a class that represents this server.
Thanks
[what this port looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzoG8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You normally use the Eclipse Help System to display help pages:

```java
IWorkbenchHelpSystem helpSys = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem();

helpSys.displayHelp("help context id");
```

Comment: Thank you, I think this might be a better approach than what I am trying.
Will test it.